# Error given when running the program in gdb debugger

Tags: c, gdb

When I run the program in gdb it is giving the error  "Program exited normally" can anybody help me to come out this problem.

Comment: Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffc604) at src/simulator.c:1405
1405                            case 1:read_file("A");
(gdb) n
cmh_req.txt or test_log.txt: File Open Error
Program exited with code 01.

Comment: read_file (arg=0x1 <Address 0x1 out of bounds>) at src/simulator.c:694
694     {
(gdb) n

Program exited normally.

Answer (score 0):

It means the program has finished the execution.
Try to set break boint before running it if you want to debug the code.

Comment: i have set the break point but still when the programme reach the break point and when i execute that line the programme normally exiting

Comment: when i run the programme in gdb and set the break point at the begining of the function.while executing the programme when it enter into the programme it is giving the error read_file (arg=0x1 <Address 0x1 out of bounds>) programme exiting normally

Answer (score 0):

Program exited normally is not an error - its telling you your program finished running without encountering any errors.

Comment: but it is not at the end of the programme. It is at the line where the function hasbeen called.So when i try to enter into the function through step command it is exited normally

Comment: read_file (arg=0x1 <Address 0x1 out of bounds>) at src/simulator.c:694
694     {
(gdb) n

Program exited normally.

Comment: when i run the programme in gdb and set the break point at the begining of the function.while executing the programme when it enter into the programme it is giving the error read_file (arg=0x1 <Address 0x1 out of bounds>) programme exiting normally.

Comment: Have you tried setting the breakpoint earlier and then step forward ?