# gdb error "Program exited normally"

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

when i bedug the programme through gdb it is giving error [Thread 0x8003 (LWP 6186) exited] and Program exited normally can any body help me to come out this problem

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate on your question by explaining what you want to do, using full words,
complete sentences and punctuation. You also need to provide more information on
your problem, such as what happens and what you expect/want.

Comment: ...most importantly you should not post duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4827605/507519

Comment: ...or triplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4654386/507519

Answer (score 8):

That is not an error, from gdb's point of view. Your program just finished gracefully, with a return value of 0, and gdb informs you of that.

You might want to set a few breakpoints before starting your program, so you can poke around in whatever you wish to see. The most obvious thing (which may or may not be useful in your case) would be

```
b main
```

Comment: +1 for bothering to answer a question that essentially boils down to "C Program exited normally in gdb. Huh?"